# Override routes in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I needed to create an estate agency online on a Joomla 3.x installation. Since I didn't code anything in Joomla since v1.5 and I forgot almost everything, and due to lack of time, I decided to do it by using a plugin for embedding PHP code within articles. So I'm using an article to list properties (real estates), whose alias is "list", and another one whose alias is "property" to view one property.

Everything is up and running, except that I'm using a unique URL for any search, which is a no no for positioning. Search variables are sent through POST, instead of using a SEF URI, because the Joomla router would interfere. To view a property, I do this

**www.example.com/property?id=***property_id*

I've been looking for a solution by hacking or overriding the Joomla router, like here: 
http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_System_Plugin_to_augment_JRouter

but there's something I'm missing or I don't get it because I can't still prevent the Joomla router from managing itself some routes I'd like to use.

I'd like to use something like

**www.example.com/list/mode/rent/type/house/city/fooville/area/downtown**

but the second segment is parsed as the article id, and any additional segment leads to a 404 error. What should I do to parse URL's like these?

I was also considering to assume the value of each segment by convention, in order to save myself the segments used to identify the values next to them, but all of them should be optional, so should I stick to a structure like above? It would be overwhelmingly long if I add the rest of search filters.

Comment: Before hacking into the Joomla core or trying things the harder way, have you taken a look at some of the free "Real Estate" extensions on the [Joomla Extensions Directory](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/vertical-markets/real-estate) ? Unfortunately I haven't tested any of them so can't give any definitive opinions, however give them a try as they could save you a lot of time :)

Comment: Hi Lodder, yes I checked them out, but the good ones seem to be commercial. And more important, in our case all the data must be retrieved in xml format from an API we made in the original server (don't ask why, they wanted it that way). So, no database interactions are being made, and that's what all the real estate extensions will deal with.

Comment: Great question! Would the "Simple Custom Router" extension help? http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/21251

Comment: Thank you Neil! Looks like a good extension! I'm testing it and I can reach the custom routes I've created. However I have problems regarding the variables I send. For example, this is the route I've created to display one property:
property/(\d+)  , equals to:  option=com_content&view=article&id=92&id={1}, and in both cases I display the same article (with custom PHP).
It is supposed that {1} will be parsed as the number specified in the second segment.
However it seems that id won't get any value. So the property profile is displayed with no data.

Comment: I happened to create a Joomla extension for displaying properties from an XML feed recently (in this case DezRez). Have a look here: http://bit.ly/185UTDK

Comment: Adam B: I've just browsed your web. Is your extension available and open source?

Answer (score 1):

If your XML retrieval is done in a custom component you wrote, you could add a router for your component. See here for info on how to do that: http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

You would add a menu link to your component in the site menu with an apropiate alias e.g. list and the Joomla Router would then call your component router for everything after /list/ .

Comment: Jan: Thanks for replying. The problem is I have little time to learn again how to create Joomla components, for v3. I did for v1.5, but the Joomla framework has changed a lot since then.